# Why would Xcode 5 not show me an installed AdHoc TestFlight provisioning profile for signing an archive for AdHoc distribution?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning, provisioning-profile, testflight

I created a distribution provisioning profile for a specific app ID for AdHoc distribution.

In Xcode under Preferences > Accounts I see the created distribution provisioning profile for TestFlight.

I duplicated the "release" build configuration and chose this "TestFlight" distribution provisioning profile for code signing.

I edited the archive scheme to use the "TestFlight" build configuration.

Then I build an archive.

When I attempt to export it for Enterprise AdHoc Distribution Xcode lists iOS Team Provisioning Profile but not the one I created for TestFlight.

What is missing?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode refused to show the distribution provisioning profile because the project bundle identifier had an uppercase letter while in the portal I created it with lowercase.

To edit the bundle identifier I went to info.plist and just changed this line:

```
com.mycompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

to something like:

```
com.mycompany.myapp
```

so, Xcode is case-senstive to identifiers.